# Stop PostgreSQL log files from filling up disk

Tags: postgresql

I'm running PostgreSQL 8.4 on an Ubuntu server. I realized that my disk is out of space because the log file had became too large. Can I adjust what gets written to the log file?

Comment: Are you talking about an actual Log that holds e.g. all the queries that have been executed or the WAL (Write Ahead Log)?

Comment: I'd have a similar question - can one decide to log into a file when in interactive 'psql' mode? In other words, to log into a file at runtime.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Edit `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf` and change or disable the various `log_*` parameters.  Then reload postgresql.

You might also want to check what gets written to the logs.  By default, there should not be that much logging.  Possibly, your application is throwing lots of errors, which is what's filling up your hard disks.

Comment: where can I find log folder?

Comment: Yeah, that directory doesn't exist anymore, unless I'm not doing something correctly.

Comment: Which directory are you referring to @Pred? /etc/postgresql/<version>/main is the directory that postgres is installed into by default on most Linux distributions.

Comment: At the point, I don't remember, lol. I think it was just a different version, or a file path than what you listed due to distro differences.